# Setting NSUserDefaults in Today Extension (iOS)

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I know that I can set NSUserDefaults within the containing app, but I want to have a button within an iOS today extension that changes between set titles when pressed.

I've tried two options already:

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:]
```

and I'm already using:

```
[prefs doubleForKey:key];
```

to retrieve what has been set within the containing app.

The problem is using

```
[prefs setDouble:value forKey:key];
```

within the Today extension freezes.

I've been looking through the documentation for anything that says that setting NSUserDefaults is not available within a Today extension, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today extensions [can share NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)!
But you need to set it up [the right way](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) ...

Comment: Reading through that documentation only suggests that what I'm doing should work fine, but it still freezes within the widget itself.